# Generalizated Pell Equation x^2-6*y^2=893053456

Tags: number-theory, pell-type-equations

x^2-6*y^2=893053456

I understand how it is

Sqrt (6) in continuous fraction: [2, (2, 4)]

And how convergents are found to find the unitary solution

2/1

5/2 => 5^2-6*2^2 = 1

22/9

49/20 => 49^2-6*20^2 = 1

218/89

485/198 => 485^2 - 6*198^2 = 1

Then (5,2) ; (49,20) ; (485,198) ecc.ecc. are unitary solutions

But I did not understand

How do I get to the solution

x=30380

y=2232

Comment: Note that $893053456 = 29884^2$. Hence, whenever $X,Y$ solves $X^2-6Y^2=1$ you have that $(29884X ; 29884Y)$ is a solution of your equation.

Comment: yes, but i search x=30380 y=2232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Legendre symbol $(6|31) = -1.$ As a result, it will be necessary for both your $x,y$ to be divisible by $31.$

$$ (6|31) = (2|31)(3|31) = (3|31) = -(31|3) = -(1|3) = -1  $$

Other than that, we can multiply things, as
$$ (x^2 - 6 y^2 )(a^2 - 6 b^2) = (ax -6yb)^2 - 6 (xb-ya)^2. $$
In particular, to square something, take $a = x$ but $b = -y$ to get
$$ (x^2 - 6 y^2 )^2 = \left(x^2 +6y^2 \right)^2 - 6 \left(2xy\right)^2. $$
Then you can use $2^2 - 6 \cdot 1^2 = -2$ and $25^2 - 6 \cdot 8^2 = 241.$

I guess I would use $5^2 - 6 \cdot 2^2 = 1$ to give
$$  20^2 - 6 \cdot 8^2 = 16 = 2^4, $$ also
$$ 1009^2 - 6 \cdot 400^2 = 58081 = 241^2,  $$ so
$$ 980^2 - 6 \cdot 72^2 = 929296 = 16 \cdot 58081 = 2^4 241^2.  $$

Once you have $u^2 - 6 v^2 = 2^4 241^2,$ then
$(31u)^2 - 6 (31v^2) = 2^4 31^2 241^2.$

=======================================

```
? factor( 893053456 )
%1 = 
[2 4]

[31 2]

[241 2]
```

=========================================================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    5   12
    2   5
  Automorphism backwards:  
    5   -12
    -2   5

  5^2 - 6 2^2 = 1

 u^2 - 6 v^2 = -2

Thu May 18 10:56:44 PDT 2017

u:  2  v:  1 ratio: 2  SEED   KEEP +- 
u:  22  v:  9 ratio: 2.44444
u:  218  v:  89 ratio: 2.44944
u:  2158  v:  881 ratio: 2.44949
u:  21362  v:  8721 ratio: 2.44949
u:  211462  v:  86329 ratio: 2.44949
u:  2093258  v:  854569 ratio: 2.44949
u:  20721118  v:  8459361 ratio: 2.44949

Thu May 18 10:57:04 PDT 2017

 u^2 - 6 v^2 = -2
```

====================================================

```
jagy@phobeusjunior:~$ ./Pell_Target_Fundamental
  Automorphism matrix:  
    5   12
    2   5
  Automorphism backwards:  
    5   -12
    -2   5

  5^2 - 6 2^2 = 1

 u^2 - 6 v^2 = 241

Thu May 18 11:00:10 PDT 2017

u:  25  v:  8 ratio: 3.125  SEED   KEEP +- 
u:  29  v:  10 ratio: 2.9  SEED   BACK ONE STEP  25 ,  -8
u:  221  v:  90 ratio: 2.45556
u:  265  v:  108 ratio: 2.4537
u:  2185  v:  892 ratio: 2.44955
u:  2621  v:  1070 ratio: 2.44953
u:  21629  v:  8830 ratio: 2.44949
u:  25945  v:  10592 ratio: 2.44949
u:  214105  v:  87408 ratio: 2.44949
u:  256829  v:  104850 ratio: 2.44949
u:  2119421  v:  865250 ratio: 2.44949
u:  2542345  v:  1037908 ratio: 2.44949
u:  20980105  v:  8565092 ratio: 2.44949
u:  25166621  v:  10274230 ratio: 2.44949

Thu May 18 11:00:30 PDT 2017

 u^2 - 6 v^2 = 241

jagy@phobeusjunior:~$
```

==================================================

Comment: How did you calculate the Legendre symbol?